# Handlebar.js to include another template in parent template

Tags: templates, handlebars.js

I have an error page , which is a handlebar.js template. I need to load this template in the current page handlebar.js template. A typical include < file name > type, but could not found a way around in handlebar. Please advise me here .

Thanks.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Sounds like you're looking for a partial. A partial is a template fragment that you want to include in several other templates. You'd do something like this in your templates:

```
<script id="error" type="text/x-handlebars">
    <!-- Error display stuff goes here -->
</script>
<script id="t" type="text/x-handlebars">
    {{> error}}
</script>
```

Then register the partial:

```
Handlebars.registerPartial('error', $('#error').html());
```

Once that's done, you can use `#t` as normal:

```
var t = Handlebars.compile($('#t').html());
var h = t({ ... });
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/P2BK7/